# Show each column for UNION statement in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have these simple SQL statements:

```
SELECT     COUNT(ID) AS Expr1
FROM         Table1
UNION
SELECT     COUNT(ID) AS Expr2
FROM         Table1 AS Table1_1
WHERE     (UPDATED > CREATED)
UNION
SELECT     COUNT(DISTINCT DATEPART(year, UPDATED)) AS Expr3
FROM         Table1 AS Table1_2
```

I want to show results as:

```
Expr1     Expr2    Expr3
-----     -----    -----
5           3         2
```

How to do that ? I understand that `UNION` is more reliable and faster than using `OR` in `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do this with `UNION` - that will give you a union of rows - not columns.

For your requirement, try something like this:

```
SELECT 
    Expr1 = (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM Table1),
    Expr2 = (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM Table1 WHERE UPDATED > CREATED),
    Expr3 = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT DATEPART(year, UPDATED)) FROM Table1)
```

That will give you one row with three columns, containing the values you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't something like

```
SELECT 
COUNT(ID) AS Expr1,
    (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM Table1 WHERE UPDATED > CREATED) as Expr2,
    COUNT(DISTINCT DATEPART(year, UPDATED) as Expr3
FROM Table1
```

what you need?